# Customize tooltip in Highcharts.js?

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have the following question:

How can I customize the chart tooltip using Highcharts.js 
library?

any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to customize the tooltip of your highcharts.js chart, you can do it defining a **formatter** 
for the tooltip property of your chart_object, like this:

```
var chart_object = {
(...)

 tooltip: {
      formatter: function() {
                             return '<span>' + 'My HTML ' +   this.x + '</span> : <b>' + this.y + '</b>';
                             }
  },
(...)
}
```

You will use the chart_object later to initialize your Highcharts chart:

```
var chart = new Highcharts.Chart(chart_object );
```

I hope it helps.